# What's stored in spatial_ref_sys?

Tags: postgresql, spatial, postgis

Should I copy data in this table when migrating to the other server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it comes with PostGIS as a standardized catalog of the spatial reference systems your database can work with. It will be recreated when you `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`.

In fact, copying the table may cause the installation of PostGIS to fail with the following error:

> ERROR:  relation "spatial_ref_sys" already exists

PostGIS is supposed to provide that table and the schema. You can see the table [documented here](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#spatial_ref_sys).

That said, if you have a custom SRS installed such as the ones provided by http://spatialreference.org you will have to copy those rows over, from the docs,

> Various US state plane spatial reference systems (meter or feet based) - usually one or 2 exists per US state. Most of the meter ones are in the core set, but **many of the feet based ones or ESRI created ones you will need to pull from spatialreference.org.**